# How can I match a delimited sentence that has at least three words and that may contain parts of delimiters?

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to match a string that would be delimited on both sides by either a ",," or "::".
It's important to note that the sentence itself could contain "," and ":", and that by sentence I mean at least two words and a space.

Example:

```
test.wav,,200,,This is a test, or is it?::test 2.wav,,test 3.wav::I said: Do not do that,,error.wav
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [],
    "match": "This is a test, or is it?"
  },
  {
    "groups": [],
    "match": "I said: Do not do that"
  }
]
```

I've tried:

1.

```
(?:,,|::)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-,?!;/\(\)]+\h){2,}.*?(?:,,|::)
```

But that gives me:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [],
    "match": ",,200,,This is a test, or is it?::"
  }
]
```

2. 

```
(?<=,,|::)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-,?!;/\(\)]+\h){2,}.*?(?:,,|::)
```

That outputs:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [],
    "match": "200,,This is a test, or is it?::"
  },
  {
    "groups": [],
    "match": "test 2.wav,,test 3.wav::"
  }
]
```

What would be the right way to go about this?

Comment: Can you show your code? How does matching a regex get you a JSON output?

Comment: I'm just using JSON as means of displaying the output; it's just PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with lookahead and lookbehind conditions:

```
(?<=,,|::)\h*(?:(?!\S*(?:,,|::))\S+\h+){3}.*?(?=::|,,)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qur2Rz/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=,,|::)`: Positive lookbehind to assert we have `,,` or `::` just before current position
- `\h*`: Match 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?!\S*(?:,,|::))`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't match `::` or `,,` as a part of next non-whitespace word
  - `\S+\h+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace string followed by 1+ whitespace
- `){3}`: End non-capture group. Match this group at least 3 times
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any character (non-greedy)
- `(?=::|,,)`: Positive lookahead to assert we have `,,` or `::` just after current position

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot. It works perfectly. I just didn't want to comment because it says not to comment just to say thanks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a pattern to match at least 2 words followed by spaces, and match at least a single char for the third word that does not have to be followed by a space.

```
(?:,,|::)\h*\K(?:(?>[^\s,:]+|,(?!,)|:(?!:))+\h+){2,}(?:(?>[^\s,:]+|,(?!,)|:(?!:)))+(?=\h*(?:,,|::))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:,,|::)\h*\K` Match either `,,` or `::` and optional spaces, then forget what is matched using `\K`
- `(?:(?>[^\s,:]+|,(?!,)|:(?!:))+\h+){2,}` Match at least 2 "words" of at least a single char not consisting of `,,` or `::`
- `(?:(?>[^\s,:]+|,(?!,)|:(?!:)))+` Match a word of at least a single char not consisting of `,,` or `::`
- `(?=\h*(?:,,|::))` Positive lookahead, assert optional spaces followed by `,,` or `::`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1aioOU/1)